# Why this jquery animate on css transform don't work in Opera

Tags: jquery, animation, transform, opera

I have a plugin for css property and animation that transform rotateX and it don't work in Opera. Anybody know why?

```
// css rotateX transformation plugin
(function($) {
    function getTransformProperty(element) {
        var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform',
                          'MozTransform', 'msTransform',
                          'OTransform'];
        var p;
        while (p = properties.shift()) {
            if (element.style[p] !== undefined) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    var property = getTransformProperty(document.createElement('div'));

    if (property) {
        $.cssHooks['rotateX'] = {
            get: function(elem, computed, extra){
                return elem.style[property].replace(/.*rotateX\((.*)deg\).*/, '$1');
            },
            set: function(elem, value){
                value = parseInt(value);
                $(elem).data('roateX', value);
                if (elem.style[property].match(/rotateX/)) {
                    var rotation = value == 0 ? '' : 'rotateX(' + value%360 + 'deg)';
                    elem.style[property] = elem.style[property].replace(/rotateX\([0-9]+deg\)/, rotation);
                } else {
                    elem.style[property] += 'rotateX(' + value%360 + 'deg)';
                }
            }
        };
        $.fx.step['rotateX'] = function(fx){
            $.cssHooks['rotateX'].set(fx.elem, fx.now);
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

It seams that getTransformProperty always return first value from the array.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGUkh/). (rotation should change on click).

Answer (score 0):

The rotateX is 3d transform which is [not supported by Opera](http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1486-css3-3d-transforms-overview/). (tested in Opera 12.15).